# startDate shows twice in FullCalendar plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the FullCalendar plugin for one of my projects. When user clicks on one area of the calendar then it shows a popup with input and Appointment button. When user clicks on the Appointment button then `makeAppointment` function is called where I simply echo `startDate` to the console.

For the first time when user clicks on the Appointment button, it logs selected date and time. When user selects "second date and time" and clicks on Appointment button on popup, it shows two dates and times i.e. one previous date and time and one currently selected date and time. Same goes for third and forth time. **Why it has this behavior and how can I fix it?**

Here is my code

```
var Calendar = {
    init: function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay',
                ignoreTimezone: false
            },
            select: this.select
        });
    },

    select: function (startDate, endDate, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        Calendar.Dialog.init(startDate, endDate);
    },

    Dialog: {
        init: function (startDate, endDate) {
            this.show();
            $('.overlay').on('click', function () { Calendar.Dialog.close() });
            $('#appointmentButton').on('click', function () { Calendar.Dialog.makeAppointment(startDate, endDate) });
        },

        //show and close functions are here

        makeAppointment: function (startDate, endDate) {
            console.log(startDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still waiting for help. Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check first if the Dialog has been initialized, otherwise don't do it again.

```
    var Calendar = {
    init: function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay',
                ignoreTimezone: false
            },
            select: this.select
        });
    },

    initialized: false,

    select: function (startDate, endDate, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        if (this.initialized === false) {
            this.initialized = true;
            Calendar.Dialog.init(startDate, endDate);
        }
    },

    Dialog: {
        init: function (startDate, endDate) {
            this.show();
            $('.overlay').on('click', function () { Calendar.Dialog.close() });
            $('#appointmentButton').on('click', function () { Calendar.Dialog.makeAppointment(startDate, endDate) });
        },

        //show and close functions are here

        makeAppointment: function (startDate, endDate) {
            console.log(startDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it doesn't even initialize the pop at all.

Comment: When I do `console.log(this.initialized)` then it returns `undefined`

Comment: You need to pass the context explicitly (apply(), call()) or call it in the instance.